# How to check if a form is closed in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

After calling:

```
 Form1.Close();
```

How can I know if this form has been really closed or it has been cancelled in *FormCloseQuery* using *CanClose:=false* ?

**UPDATE:**

For better explanation: there is *MainForm* that can close a child form called *Form1*. So, my question is when *MainForm* calls to *Form1.Close()*, how *MainForm* can know that Form1 has been really closed and not canceled from its *FormCloseQuery* ?
*Form1* is destroyed if it is closed. Is there a way to see if *Form1* has been destroyed after calling *Close()* ?

Comment: When you set `CanClose` to false in `FormCloseQuery`, you know that it has been cancelled, no?

Comment: There's no LastCloseCancelled property, so you can't. Mosts probably there's a solution to your problem but that would depend on context.

Comment: What happens when you close it? Is it destroyed or hidden? Either way it's easy to check whether that actually happened.

Comment: Nil the variable in MainForm's unit when the form is destroyed. Then you can test if it is assigned. Alternatively you can consult to screen.forms.

Comment: But note that destruction due to a close is asynchronous, in no case the form is destroyed right after the close call.

Comment: You can add some processing in the `OnDestroy` event.

Comment: Or in OnClose, which will not be called if CloseQuery returns false.

Answer (score 0):

> *Form1* is destroyed if it is closed. Is there a way to see if *Form1* has been destroyed after calling *Close()* ?

In that case, in Form1's `OnDestroy` event, you can set the global `Form1` variable to `nil`, and then you can check if `Form1` is `nil` when needed.

```pascal
var
  Form1: TForm1;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := ...;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1 := nil;
end;

...

if Form1 <> nil then
  ...
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I never use global variables, I deleted all of them in my projects. Maybe I could use a derived class of TForm and to add a "IsClosed" variable, assigned in FormDestroy. However I am not clear if I can check a member variable after calling Close if Action = caFree.

Comment: @kokokok `caFree` is asynchronous, so you can access a member after `Close()` until the moment the Form is actually destroyed. So making `IsClosed` a member won't really work. But since the Form is not auto-created (you need a global for that), then whatever code creates the Form and stores the pointer can assign an `OnDestroy` handler to reset that pointer when destroyed.

Comment: @kokokok You can do whatever you want in `OnDestroy`. For example you can notify the main window that the form is being destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I use decision, that can help you.
You can declare new global variable(container), which will save your windows.

```
WindowsList: TObjectList<Tform>
```

And for event `OnCreate` you can do following operation:

```
  WindowList.Add(Self);
```

And for event `OnDestroy` you can do:

```
  WindowList.Remove(Self);
```

And when you need find window, you will iterate over list and find necessary window, for example, by Tag and ClassName.
In my case I wrote new class, that inherits TForm, and use it class for MdiChild forms. In that class I overloaded methods `Create` and `Destroy`. And in these methods I use `WindowList.Add(Self)` and `WindowList.Remove(Self)`.

And for WindowsList I created a new class, and in that class I wrote method `FindWindow`.